# tmux-aware terminal programs

Tags: tmux

iTerm on OSX features tmux support for opening windows and tabs.  I haven't found anything similar on ubuntu:  Is this the case?

In its absence, what's the workflow for having multiple persistent sessions on a remote host?  Switching [C-b n] seems really clunky.

Comment: Yes, [tmux](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/tmux) exists for Ubutnu, and a lot of people recommend it. Others prefer [screen](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/screen). Myself, I just use multiple ssh sessions, and while they aren't persistent, I rarely, if ever, have a problem.

Comment: I'm aware tmux exists, what I'm wondering about is a terminal variant which can open multiplexed windows and tabs.  iTerm does this on OSX.

Comment: Yes.  iTerm tmux support opens up a new session on the remote machine which can survive a network disconnect.